# Exactly sum the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^nn}$

Tags: real-analysis

So I have started by finding that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$ has a radius of convergence of 1. I would think that I need to use this to solve it by differentiating it and substituting in some value of x to make it my formula. I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Integrate the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^n$ term by term and then shift the index.

Comment: the sum is in $i$ or in $n$?

Comment: My mistake- it is for n @Riccardo.Alestra

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor Series for $$\log(1-x)= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} $$

Set $x=\frac 12$ to get $$-\log(1-\frac 12) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^n} = \log 2$$